# null Order on custom controller

Tags: magento2, php, controllers

Im in a custom controller tying to get the order info with checkout session. There is my code.

```
    $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder(); // Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor
    $orderId = $order->getEntityId(); // null
    $orderIncrementId = $order->getIncrementId(); // null
```

But actually Im getting null on $orderId and $orderIncrementId.

Seems like the order is not being correctly placed.

Comment: Where you put the code is important, the reason is the last order is not persist in checkout_session. I suggest you first check with checkout order success event first.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :-**

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession =  $checkoutSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
      } // close bracket
    public function getLastOrder()
    {
        return $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getEntityId();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try like this:

```
<?php
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Session $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function getOrderInfo() {
         $orderId = $this->checkoutSession->getData('last_order_id');
    }
?>
```